# Need ALL data from a table with JOIN to another table with multile AND on multiple ROW

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i need to use parameters of IN clause with AND Clause.

i am having a table

```
        HOTEL
 ______________________
 | id | name | address |
 ______________________
 | 1  | A    | ABC     |
 ______________________
 | 2  | B    | BCD     |
 ______________________
```

TABLE 2

```
    AMENITY
 _____________
 | id | name |
 _____________
 | 1  | X    |
 _____________
 | 2  | Y    |
 _____________
 | 3  | Z    |
 _____________
```

TABLE 3

```
  HOTEL AMENITY
 _____________________________
 | id | hotel_id | amenity_id |
 _____________________________
 | 1  | 1        |     1      |
 _____________________________
 | 2  | 1        |     2      |
 _____________________________
```

I need to find hotels with amenity X and Z . 
 I am using QUERY LIKE

```
  SELECT `h.id` , `h.name`  FROM `hotel` AS `h` 
  INNER JOIN `hotel_amenity` AS `ha` ON `h`.`id` = `ha`.`hotel_id` 
  INNER JOIN `amenity` AS `a` ON `ha`.`amenity_id` = `a`.`id` 
  WHERE 
  `a`.`id` IN( '1' , '3') 
  GROUP BY `h`.`id`
```

This provinding all hotels with both aminities with or clause , is there a way to use this IN clause with AND
OR can i provide ALL clause here.

Comment: Your question is little ambiguous as to what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already filter it an group.. It should be grouping and then check for expected.. `HAVING` does it.

```
  SELECT `h.id` , `h.name`  FROM `hotel` AS `h` 
  INNER JOIN `hotel_amenity` AS `ha` ON `h`.`id` = `ha`.`hotel_id` 
  INNER JOIN `amenity` AS `a` ON `ha`.`amenity_id` = `a`.`id` 
  GROUP BY `h`.`id` 
  HAVING COUNT( case when a.id in (1,3) then 1 else null end ) = 2
```